# Magento Custom Product Collection Pagination Not working

Tags: magento, collections, pagination, toolbar, product

I am displaying the Bestseller product listing in the CMS page by using the XML Layout for rendering the block. Together with the pagination, i need to display the toolbar (pagination and sorting) as in other product listings. Therefore i have created a custom module for that. With that, i am able to display the products listing and the toolbar appears as well. But the Sorting (or any features) doesnot seem to work. Please help me out. My code is as follows.

```
class MyCompany_Bestseller_Block_Bestseller extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract  //Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
        $collection = $this->getBestsellerProduct();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
  }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

    $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->getCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }

        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);

        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bestseller/toolbar', microtime());
        return $block;
    }
    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }

    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    } 

  function getBestsellerProduct()
  { 

    // store ID
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();      

    // get most ordered products
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
                    ->addOrderedQty()
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)                    
                    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');                                      

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
            ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
            ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    return $products; 
  }
}
```

The Toolbar.php block code for my module is as follows:

```
class MyCompany_Bestseller_Block_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        $pagerBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager');

        if ($pagerBlock instanceof Varien_Object) {

            /* @var $pagerBlock Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager */
            $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($this->getAvailableLimit());

            $pagerBlock->setUseContainer(false)
            ->setShowPerPage(false)
            ->setShowAmounts(false)
            ->setLimitVarName($this->getLimitVarName())
            ->setPageVarName($this->getPageVarName())
            ->setLimit($this->getLimit())
            ->setCollection($this->getCollection());
            return $pagerBlock->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Here is the xml block that i have used.

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="bestseller/bestseller" name="bestseller_list" template="bestseller/bestseller.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

I couldnot figure out the problem with the code. Please help me out.

Comment: Show also xml code for the block ??

Comment: I have also added the xml code for the block now.

Comment: @Rujen Have you got any solution I have faced issue in custom pagination ?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316910/magento-2-custom-added-ajax-pagination-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my collection already being loaded. This keeps all the filters in the pager from being applied. Try changing your constructor to

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $collection = $this->getBestsellerProduct()->clear();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
}
```

If you are loading the bestseller collection again some where say by calling count on it. Then try

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $collection = clone $this->getBestsellerProduct();
    $this->setCollection($collection->clear());
}
```

Hope this gets you where you need to be

Comment: I have faced issue in custom pagination ? please check the issue.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316910/magento-2-custom-added-ajax-pagination-not-working